# How to use a windows based android emulator avd data in linux?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, android, emulators

I had before in my machine running Windows 10, then I decided to switch back again to Arch Linux. Before installing Arch Linux I backed up my hidden Android directory that has AVD data directory which is located in:

**C:\Users\Khalid\.android**

After switching to Arch, I installed android emulator on it and added all the the required environment variables by the android emulator to .bashrc, these are the environment variables defined:

```
export EXTERNAL_DRIVE=/run/media/user12/EXTERN_DRIVE/Android
export ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
export ANDROID_EMULATOR=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator
export ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME=$EXTERNAL_DRIVE/.android/
export ANDROID_AVD_HOME=$ANDROID_EMULATOR_HOME/avd/
export ANDROID_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools
export ANDROID_CMDLINE_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/cmdline-tools/tools/bin
export ANDROID_PLATFORMS=$EXTERNAL_DRIVE/android-sdk/platforms
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/platforms
```

After that I listed the available avds by executing the command:

**`avdmanager list avd`**

But I get an error:

```
    The following Android Virtual Devices could not be loaded:
        Name: Nexus_5X_API_26_Google_Play
        Path: /run/media/user12/EXTERN_DRIVE/Android/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_26_Google_Play.ini
       Error: Corrupted AVD ini file: /run/media/user12/EXTERN_DRIVE/Android/.android/avd/Nexus_5X_API_26_Google_Play.ini
    ---------
        Name: Nexus_5_API_23_Marshmallow
        Path: /run/media/user12/EXTERN_DRIVE/Android/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_23_Marshmallow.ini
       Error: Corrupted AVD ini file: /run/media/user12/EXTERN_DRIVE/Android/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_23_Marshmallow.ini
```

I also tried to see if I am going to emulate the machine by doing:

**`emulator -avd Nexus_5X_API_26_Google_Play`**

But I got the following error:

```
PANIC: Cannot find AVD system path. Please define ANDROID_SDK_ROOT
```

Can anyone tell me what could be wrong about this or why I am I getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you were supposed to use import not export.  You could also have done it with Android studio already running as it offers to import and export images from a gui interface.  You can refer here

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#importexporthp

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds#selecthardwarepage